mpl-token-metadata
I am trying to update NFT metadata using mpl-token-metadata 5.1.0.
But I can't find the function like update_metadata_accounts_v2() in docs.
I am using anchor version 0.29.0, Solana-cli 1.18.16, mpl-token-metadata 5.1.0.
Where can I get resource for this work?
Thank you.

You can check out all available instructions in the docs, via https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/instructions/index.html
In particular, you are interested in the UpdateAsUpdateAuthorityV2 instruction builder
 pub fn update_metadata(
        ctx: Context<UpdateMetadata>,
        name: String,
        symbol: String,
        uri: String,
        seller_fee_basis_points: u16,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let data = Data {
            name,
            symbol,
            uri,
            seller_fee_basis_points,
            creators: None, //! update with creators if needed
        };

        UpdateAsUpdateAuthorityV2CpiBuilder::new(&ctx.accounts.metadata_program.to_account_info())
            .authority(&ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info())
            .mint(&ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info())
            .metadata(&ctx.accounts.metadata_account)
            .payer(&ctx.accounts.authority)
            .system_program(&ctx.accounts.system_program)
            .sysvar_instructions(&ctx.accounts.sysvar_instruction.to_account_info())
            .data(data)
            .invoke()?;

        Ok(())
    }

Accounts required for this
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateMetadata<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata_account: Account<'info, MetadataAccount>,

    pub metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    /// CHECK: ok
    pub sysvar_instruction: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

ref: https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/instructions/struct.UpdateAsUpdateAuthorityV2CpiBuilder.html
edit: removed data being passed in as struct and using parameters defined in the Data struct

Thank you for your kind explanation.
But, I wanna update NFT metadata uri.
Could you let me know about this part?

updated my answer

But there is also bug in accounts context.
Could you let me know about the sysvar_instruction?

sysvar are read-only accounts that give us information about the network. instructions sysvar contain the serialized instructions in a Message while that Message is being processed, ref from docs

Thanks for your kind help.
